# Running a PHP script gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, html, cpanel

Recently I installed cPanel on my vps with centOS.Now my PHP files are returning a 500 Internal Server error. HTML files work fine however. 
Always when i try to enter php file it says 500 Internal server error...

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file with php_flags or php.ini file?

Comment: I have .htaccess, but no php_flags, do i need it, and how to set it ?

Comment: You don't need it. Just make sure the file permissions are 644 just like @Daniele B 's link sais.

Comment: file permissions are 644 for files, and for directories 755..

Comment: You said no .htaccess file, but is there a php.ini? Btw .htaccess files are (on linux) by default hidden (any filename preceded by a dot marks a hidden file). Set your ftp show you hidden files.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa is right: the server error logs will tell you exactly what the problem is. There are many reasons why a server might report error 500 and the solution will be different for each of them. The logs will have the detail that will tell you what the problem is; without that detail, no-one can really tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The most probable is that you have wrong permissions on folders or files.

A PHP file must usually have permissions set to 644 and its containing folder to 755.

If you want to be sure permissions re right, you can use a "fast and dirty solution" setting everything to 777 (and reversing the change immediately for secvurity reasons of course).

Also, the problem could hide in the .htaccess file, as reported here
http://www.2mhost.com/kb/view/147

Or even in the php.ini as reported here:
https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/prbasicts.html

hope this helps

Comment: [Links are not answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), try to make your answer stand alone, and offer the link as proof or a supporting argument or as a detailed explanations etc.